# Azure add user to subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am almost new to Azure. My client had created an Azure account and sent invitation to me. I had accepted her invitation to join her Azure portal. However when I log in with my username, it shows me "No subscription". My client is saying she has given me every access rights, but I am not able to do anything there. Even I am not sure if I have really joined her Azure portal.

Here is the image if when I tried to access Free Services.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what i understand is that the current directory you are working in doesn't have the rights that you are expecting. And your client has added you to another subscription with all the required rights. All you need to do is switch your directory to the one which has the subscription provided by your client.

1. Just Click on your profile avatar(or name) on the top right of the portal.
   [image]
2. Select the option `Switch Directory` form the pop-up.

[image]

And choose your concerned directory + Subscription.

Comment: No, I dont think so I need to change the directory. I have said in the question that I want to join the client's azure subscription and she has told me that she has created my username there, but still it is not letting me to do anything.

Comment: @azharrahi In the classic portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com), adding you as a co-administrator is enough to give you full access to the subscription.

However, in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com), you should be added as a Co-Owner through the RBAC system. Someone with an appropriate role should go to Browse > Subscriptions > "subscription_name" > All settings > Users to add you with the Owner role for example.

Does it help?